# Send SOAP request using CURL

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am sending a soap request using PHP curl(). I need to print my request, so that I can have a look into my request and understand weather it is going in a right format.

Here is my code:

```
$parameters = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:ejb='http://ejb.gateway.ebpp.fawryis.com/'>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ejb:process>
//... 
      </ejb:process>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";


$url='//URL to the service';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'utf-8');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
    'SOAPAction:""', 
    'Content-Type: text/xml; 
    charset=utf-8',
));

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

I get a wrong data sent error from the API side which means I am not sending a correct format.
Can anyone please let me know how to do that?

Update:
Verbose information

```
* About to connect() to 10.2.250.4 port 9081 (#0)
*   Trying 10.2.250.4...
* connected
* Connected to 10.2.250.4 (10.2.250.4) port 9081 (#0)
> POST /CoreWeb/ApplicationBusinessFacadeService HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.2.250.4:9081
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: utf-8
SOAPAction:""
Content-Type: text/xml; 
    charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1087
Expect: 100-continue

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 14:04:19 GMT
< Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 14:04:19 GMT
< Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 914
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.2.250.4 left intact
```

Comment: Why not use PHP's SoapClient?  Also it's impossible to say what the correct format should be without knowing the specific details of the specific SOAP call you're trying to make.

Comment: because I want the generated XML in a format that is different than the one that SOAP/Nusoap client gives to me

Answer (score 2):

Your Header is broken into two lines:

```
'Content-Type: text/xml; 
charset=utf-8',
```

Make it in one line. May be it is causing the problem for you.

```
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
```

**UPDATE:**

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
   'SOAPAction:""', 
   'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8',
   'Expect:'
));
```

Comment: Edited it but the same problem :-(

Comment: Run the code with `curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and update your code with the verbose output so that we can dig further and help you.

Comment: Your XML's content size is more than 1024 characters. That's why it is sending `Expect: Continue` header with your request. Also add this `'Expect:'` header inside the array of `HTTPHEADER`. See my updated answer for this.

Comment: Now it gives:* About to connect() to 10.2.250.4 port 9081 (#0)
*   Trying 10.2.250.4...
* connected
* Connected to 10.2.250.4 (10.2.250.4) port 9081 (#0)
> POST /CoreWeb/ApplicationBusinessFacadeService HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.2.250.4:9081
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: utf-8
SOAPAction:""
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1087

* upload completely sent off: 1087 out of 1087 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en-US
< Content-Length: 914
< Date: Thu, 20 Mar 2014 15:04:17 GMT